# Calculate with values in a lookup

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

we have built a list which lookups an amount in another table. This value is depending on other criteria in this list and we need to calculate a total. The output is hourly salary x hours worked. I know you need somehow a workflow but I cannot find a workable explanations of this formula. Anyone a clear explanation?
Thx

I have added the formula now: [image]

But the result is zero:
Postion2:NL is a lookup value
Worked hours to charge is filled in field (default is 0)
Vartotlhours is created 
Test is the output field in the list

What is going wrong?

Comment: Which value do you get from lookup? Salary amount??

Comment: Yes that is correct Ganesh

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

You can achieve this easily using Workflow.

You can implement one workflow on item created and changed events and calculate the `output(hourly salary x hours worked)` each time you edit the list item.

**Steps**:

You can create a SharePoint designer 2013 list workflow on your list.

1. Create two number fields `NoOfHoursWorked` and `TotalAmount`. Set default value of this column to `0`.
2. Create SharePoint designer 2013 List workflow on `On Item Create` and `On Item Edit` events.
3. In your workflow use `Calculate` action to perform multiplication of `NoOfHoursWorked` and `Hourly Salary`.
4. Update `TotalAmount` field with the result of the addition.

**For Reference**:
See my answer and reference given in below link:

[Calculating the total of numbers input in a field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255899/calculating-the-total-of-numbers-input-in-a-field/255901)

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: Not yet Ganesh, I will try tomorrow.

Comment: I have add the two colums in the list, but I am stuck at the second point? I can not find On Item create and edit?

Comment: See this image. There are the start options in the settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXO5r.png

Comment: I have added an example to my question as there is no output